# SQLBindParameter(), CALLing stored procedure with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, db2, websphere

I am trying to call a stored procedure which has an INPUT TIMESTAMP parameter.  I am using a statement with parameter markers, so I am using SQLPrepare().  I am able to set up the TIMESTAMP parameter with SQLBindParameter() like so:

```
    SQLINTEGER  dateLength = effectiveDate.length();
    sqlRet = SQLBindParameter(hnd_SQL_Stmt, parameterIndex++, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_CHAR, SQL_CHAR,
            dateLength, 0, (SQLPOINTER)effectiveDate.c_str(), 0, &dateLength);
```

If I wanted to pass in CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, how would I do that?  Passing in that value results in "Syntax of date, time, or timestamp value not valid."  For kicks I tried TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).  Nah.  :-)

Comment: Either supply a previously-retrieved  value for CURRENT TIMESTAMP, or change your stored procedure in such a way that a null or empty-value for that parameter causes the stored-procedure to choose CURRENT TIMESTAMP. This could be done via default parameters (for SQL PL procedure) or by code inside the stored procedure. Separately, it's unclear from your question why you are using strings for timestamps instead of SQL_C_TYPE_TIMESTAMP with SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP ( assuming the input parameter datatype is actually TIMESTAMP and not varchar/char ).

Comment: Additionally if the stored-procedure signature has the timestamp parameter as varchar(or char) then you can ajust the code of the stored-procedure to first compare the supplied value with CURRENT TIMESTAMP and on match then do the relevant conversion.  If you cannot change the stored-procedure your only option may be to retrieve a value for CURRENT TIMESTAMP in your application code, and supply that value for the parameter.